# Horizontal menu in center

Tags: html, css, navigation

doing this for the first time so please be gentle. :) I am aiming for navigation menu in the centre, horizontal, with image in the middle list item. Image will be much bigger as the bottom half is name of the my company and top of the picture might be touching the top. My first problem is that the li elements are only as big as the text, whitch doesnt serve the center-thing purpouse and the second one related that it stretches the whole menu when hoovered on. Please I'm looking for solution where the text is in the middle of li and img sits down on bottom. Thanks so much for help!

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><span><a href="/1.html">Link 1</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="/2.html">Link 2</a></span></li>
    <span><li style="text-algin:bottom;"><a href="/3.html"><img src="Linbach_tuzka.png" height="175px" alt="Domu"></a></li></span>
    <li><span><a href="/4.html">Link 4</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="/5.html">Link 5</a></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```
body {
width: auto;
background-image: url(blue4.jpg);
background-size: cover;
margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

#menu {
height:210px;
line-height:36px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
width:800px;
padding:0;
}

#menu ul {
display: inline;
-webkit-padding-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-before: 2x;
-webkit-margin-after: 0px;
margin:0;
font-size: 0;
} 


#menu ul li {
text-algin:center;
display:inline;
font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
font-size:40px;
padding:0;
margin:0;
text-decoration:none;
background-image:url(../Pics/Buttons/Menu/Menu.gif);
min-width:100px !important;
}

#menu a {
text-decoration:none;
color:#000000;
margin:10px 0;
padding:0;
}

#menu a:hover {
font-weight:bolder;
}

span {
width:100%;
font-size:30px;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Two typos for "align"

Comment: 1) `<span>` might not be a valid element directly under `<ul>`; 2) `bottom` might not be a valid value for `text-align`.

Comment: is there a value 'bottom' for text-align property?!!

Comment: tilwin Joy is correct - there is no 'bottom' property on text-align...
for vertical-align, there is a 'bottom' property

Comment: Never used jsFiddle, but I'll try, was looking for smthing like that. ; yeah, bottom was just shot in the dark

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pmkjj/

Comment: everything is in center here. and you are making text bold on hover which will definitely stretch your menu. one suggestion is DO NOT use `<span>` direct in `<ul>`

Comment: Yes, but if the li width will remain the same, it shouldn't do the thing, right?

Comment: Not getting you. You want to give fix width to li ? Cant you give some other effect on hover so that menu will not stretch.

Comment: I'll probably have to do that, but not the solution. Still, if you change li text to some words with different lengh it won't be centered anymore. Li needs to remain same size I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only option is left is width to `<a>` tag : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pmkjj/2/)

I have removed the direct `<span>` from `UL` and have added class 'widthAuto' so that it will not affect your logo.

```
#menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:0;
    min-width:100px !important; display:inline-block;
}
```

Note : Menu will stretch on hover if text exceed `min-width`.